# Cordova Launch storyboard Images not carrying over

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm trying to use the [newly suggested](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/index.html#launch-storyboard-images) approach for including Story board images in my Cordova app. The images however aren't carrying over to my Xcode project after running `cordova prepare ios`. Has anyone gotten Splashscreen images to work properly using StoryBoard Launch Images in Cordova?

```
<platform name="ios">
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" />
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@2x~universal~comany.png" />
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@2x~universal~comcom.png" />
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@3x~universal~anyany.png" />
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@3x~universal~anycom.png" />
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@3x~universal~comany.png" />
</platform>
```

Comment: Are you using cordova-ios@4.3.0? You can run `cordova platforms ls` to check your version.

Comment: There was a problem with the storyboard images on 4.3.0, will be fixed in 4.3.1

Comment: i am using cordova-ios@4.3. Has 4.3.1 been released yet?

Comment: It was working for me on master version: `cordova platform rm ios && cordova platform add https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios`

Comment: The image is now showing with the latest repo but the image is disappearing after 1 second, then shows a white screen, then my app appears (however I set the splash* preferences)

Comment: > the image is disappearing after 1 second, then shows a white screen, then my app appears...

I have the same problem in 4.3.1. @johnborges Have you solved this?

Comment: @cither I'll test later today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed for me as of cordova-ios@4.3.1